# Emberjs - Two custom adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, indexeddb, web-sql

I'm developing an app that need to use indexedDB to store some information offline, but in the case of Safari, its not available (yet), so I need to use webSQL.

I already use [this](https://github.com/kurko/ember-indexeddb-adapter) adapter for indexedDB, with [enter link description here](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim) polyfill for the case of browser that doesn't support indexedDB.

Unfortunatelly, I have some major issue with the Shim, for example, on iOS Safari and Safari, when, in my app, I need to fetch some data inside the database to see if it exist it return me errors.

Like this and that :

```
throwDOMException@http://localhost/Dev/Websites/myWebsite/js/libs/IndexedDBShim.js:40:16

Error: Assertion Failed: 0: The operation failed because the requested database object could not be found. For example, an object store did not exist but was being opened
```

And this is caused by the fact that they are using kind of a hack to return some value, and even in the polyfill they say this :

`// The IndexedDB Specification needs us to return an Object Store immediatly, but WebSQL does not create and return the store immediatly
// Hence, this can technically be unusable, and we hack around it, by setting the ready value to false`

So my question is, with the indexedDB adapter, can I add an other adapter for webSQL in parallel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option would be to chose the correct adapter at runtime (is that what you mean by parallel?). It should be as simple as this:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.deferReadiness();

if (window.indexedDB) {
    App.ApplicationAdapter = IndexedDBAdapter;
} else {
    App.ApplicationAdapter = WebSQLAdapter;
}

App.advanceReadiness();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed ! But I could only find one adapter for websql on the web, do you know if there is some that are actually updated ?

Comment: Unfortunately, most adapters for Ember-Data don't really get updated too often. Most of them are created then forgotten. My suggestion would be to write your own adapter. The first one should only take you a few hours. Plus, this way it'll do exactly what you need. EDIT: So to answer your question, no, I didn't find any up-to-date ones.

Comment: That's what I thought, I will write my own, and I might update it, and share it, maybe that would help someone else ^^. Thanks again !